# Proof that $\lim \frac{f}{g} = \frac{f'}{g'}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

"Let $f$ and $g$ be differentiable at $x_0$ and $f(x_0) = g(x_0)=0$, and $g'(x_0)\neq0$. Show that $$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f}{g}=\frac{f'(x_0)}{g'(x_0)}.$$

We have $$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{\lim f(x_0)}{\lim g(x_0)}=\frac{0}{0}$$

by differentiability at $x_0$ $\implies$ continuity at $x_0$. Initially I used L'Hospital here, but actually we don't know that $g'(x)\neq 0$, so thats a question mark for now. If we can use the rule here, we would have the result $$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=\frac{\lim f'(x)}{\lim g'(x)}=\frac{f'(x_0)}{g'(x_0)}(1)$$

The limit of a derivative is then a limit of another limit. I interpret this as a limit of two variables, e.g $$\lim_{(x,h) \to (x_0,0)}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}.$$

The inconsistency in the use of L'Hospital, as well as the fact that result $(1)$ implies the continuity of both derivatives makes me think this is not the correct way to do this proof - yet the indeterminate form given by continuity at $x_0$ makes me think otherwise. How should the indeterminate form be interpreted here?

Comment: If $g'(x_0)=0$ then the right hand side of the first identity does not make much sense...

Comment: I think in the 1st line, you want $g'(x_0)\ne0$.

Comment: yes that was a mistake

Comment: Then what is your question? What you have *is* L'Hospital's rule, and your statement *“actually we don't know that $'() \ne 0$”* does not apply anymore.

Comment: We know that $g'(x_0)$ is not zero, however L'Hospital requires that $g'(x)\neq 0$ for all $x$ in the domain right?